# GetDate from datepicker of the other months

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, getdate

I need your help with a problem in Datapicker. I am starting works with JQuery, and I need to do an agenda, when the user click in some day of the calendar, I need get this date to capture all schedule of the day selected.

Problem: When I click in any day of the current month, ok, all occurs correctly, I can getDate selected, but, when I click in the day of next month I didn't get the Date.

I already tried different source, but without success, when I used OnSelect, the calendar hide.

Below, the source code that I used with Jquery.ui:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>


     <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                dayNames:    ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
                dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
                monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Mar&ccedilo','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov'],
                nextText: 'Próximo',
                prevText: 'Anterior',
            });

            $("#datepicker td").click(function(){
                var dia = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getDate();  
                var mes = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;
                var ano = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
                alert(dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano);
            }); 
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="datepicker">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?
Add this to your $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker:

```
showOtherMonths: true,
selectOtherMonths: true
```